# Specifying key with $add?

Tags: angularfire

I would like to index customers in the data store using their email address as key, to enforce uniqueness.

I'm initialising my connection as follows:

```js
var ref = new Firebase("https://[myApp].firebaseio.com/");
$scope.customers = $firebase(ref.child("customers")).$asArray();
```

And here's my controller:

```js
function customerCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.addNewMember = function (firstName, lastName, email) {
        $scope.customers.$add({
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            email: email
        });
    }
}
```

Of course, this generates a unique key like `-Jbd4KJ_CrFqlpnqbGVu`. Is there a way to set the key manually instead, so that my data will look like this?

```js
{
  'bob.smith@example.com': {
    firstName: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  },
  'jane.doe@example.com': {
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName: 'Doe'
  },
  ...
}
```

Or, am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a collection (to use $asArray) if you are working with a specific path with a key you already know. You'd probably be ahead to work directly with a Firebase reference in that case.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://[myApp].firebaseio.com/");
$scope.customers = $firebase(ref.child("customers")).$asArray();
$scope.addNewMember = function(firstName, lastName, email) {
   var escapedEmail = escapeEmailAddress(email);
   ref.child('customers/'+escapedEmail).set({firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email});
};

function escapeEmailAddress(email) {
   return (email||'').replace(/\./g, ',');
}
```

The data will automatically be synchronized into $scope.customers in real-time.

If you're set on doing this through the synchronized array, then manually declare the $id and use $save instead:

```
$scope.addNewMember = function (firstName, lastName, email) {
   var rec = {
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      email: email,
      $id: escapeEmailAddress(email)
   };
   $scope.customers.push(rec);
   $scope.customers.$save(rec);
};
```

Comment: Just needed to amend the escape function to do a global replace, i.e. `return (email || '').replace(/\./g, ',')`.

Comment: Ah, right! Thanks John. That's the result of programming in too many languages in one day.